# What does "sen" in senTestCase mean?

Tags: ios, objective-c

The question says it all.

Who came up with the name?

Just curious about etymology.

Comment: +1 Was curious too, IMO this question shouldn't be closed.

Answer (score 2):

The SenTestingKit framework is Apple's fork/derivative of [OCUnit](http://www.sente.ch/software/ocunit/), a unit testing framework written by [Swiss software company "Sen:te"](http://www.sente.ch/), hence the name.

Comment: Any reason for the unaccept?

Comment: I suppose to self-answer using the information provided by previous answerers...

Answer (score 1):

The name comes from the name of a Swiss software company "Sen:te" that created the SenTestingKit framework. "Sente" means doing important things first and urgent things later. Here, what's urgent could be pushing code, and what's important could be testing.

According to [Sen:te's site](http://www.sente.ch/?page_id=170&lang=en),

> To be sente, in Japanese, means to have the initiative. This is a key
>   concept of strategic games like Go. It can also be understood as doing
>   something new before the others, or doing important things first,
>   instead of urgent things later.

Sen:te wrote OCUnit in 1998. Apple decided to integrate unit testing in Xcode 2.1 and chose OCUnit.

Answer (score 0):

It's from [Sen:te](http://www.sente.ch/software/ocunit/), the company who developed `OCUnit`.